# Passing a class with string array member to web service

Tags: c#, arrays, string, web-services

I have the following class in a web service:

```
[Serializable]
public class WebServiceParam
{
    public string[] param;
}
```

In the client application:

```
string[] reportFields = new string[] { "invoiceNo", "sale", "item", "size", "missingQty", "Country", "auto" };
param.ReportFields = reportFields;
serviceInstance.CreateReport(param);
```

However, the string array member is "null"

Here is my web service class:

```
[WebService(Description = "Service related to producing various report formats", Namespace = "http://www.apacsale.com/ReportingService")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ReportingService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    ReportingServiceImpl m_reporting;
    [WebMethod]
    public string CreateReport(ReportingParameters param)
    {
        if (param != null)
        {
            m_reporting = new ReportingServiceImpl(param);
            m_reporting.Create();
            return m_reporting.ReturnReport();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to post the webservice class. atleast the web method that you created.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is a confusion related to the `param` variable;

```
WebServiceParam temp = new WebServiceParam();
string[] reportFields = new string[] { "invoiceNo", "sale", "item", "size", "missingQty", "Country", "auto" };
temp.param = reportFields;
serviceInstance.CreateReport(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mark the class with [DataContract] attribute and the array should be property and not field. This is how your WebServiceParam should look:

```
[DataContract]
public class WebServiceParam
{
    [DataMember]
    public string[] Param {get; set;}
}
```

and the service interface would be something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void CreateReport(WebServiceParam parameters);
}
```

now you can use:

```
WebServiceParam wsParam = new WebServiceParam();
wsParam.Param = new string[] { "invoiceNo", "sale", "item", "size", "missingQty", "Country", "auto" };
serviceInstance.CreateReport(wsParam);
```